# Automatically add spaces around "=>"

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

On SublimeText 3 I try to automatically add spaces before and after "=>"

I try to add this in User Keybinding:

```
{ "keys": ["equals,>"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/User/spacer.sublime-snippet" } }
```

And this is my snippet:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[ => ]]></content>
</snippet>
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Any errors in Sublime Text console?

Comment: No, no errors. It seems that ST doesn't understand my KeyBinding (when I add a tabtrigger to my snippet it works fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console says `Unknown key equals,>`

`equals` is redundant. So correct settings:

```
{ "keys": [">"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/User/spacer.sublime-snippet" } }
```

Next time please look for errors in the console first.

UPDATE

> I want it matchs on "=>".

`["=",">"]` should be used in this case

```
{ "keys": ["=",">"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/User/spacer.sublime-snippet" } }
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I looked the console when I used the snippet but not on save, mea culpa. I tried your answer but there is a problem. It matchs on ">" but I don't want it to match on this pattern. I want it matchs on "=>". Thanks for your help

Comment: I founded the problem in the same time. There is a difference between ST2 and ST3 (ST2: ["a,b,c], ST3: ["a","b","c"]) Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

When I read the question I realized that I frequently insert spaces on both sides of something, so I knocked up the Sublime Text plugin below for my own use and, as an afterthought, decided to post it here.

This plugin adds a single space both before and after any selected text, e.g. `"Sel" --> " Sel "`. Multiple selections are, of course, handled. Single cursors are ignored otherwise you'd just be adding two spaces. It is compatible with both Sublime Text v.2 and v.3.

Save the following code in a file called `AddSpacesAroundSelection.py` and place the file somewhere in your Sublime Text Packages folder. e.g. `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/`

```py
# File:     AddSpacesAroundSelection.py
# Command:  add_spaces_around_selection
# Keys:     { "keys": ["ctrl+space"], "command": "add_spaces_around_selection" }

import sublime, sublime_plugin

class AddSpacesAroundSelectionCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    """
    The AddSpacesAroundSelectionCommand class is a Sublime Text plugin which
    adds a single space on both sides of each selection. e.g. "Sel" -> " Sel "
    """

    def run(self, edit):
        """ run() is called when the command is run. """

        space_char = " "

        # Loop through all the selections.
        for sel in self.view.sel():

            # If something is actually selected (i.e. not just a cursor) then
            # insert a space on both sides of the selected text.
            if sel.size() > 0:

                # Insert the space at the end of the selection before the
                # beginning of it or the insertion position will be wrong.
                self.view.insert(edit, sel.end(), space_char)
                self.view.insert(edit, sel.begin(), space_char)

    # End of def run()

# End of class AddSpacesAroundSelectionCommand()
```

Add a key binding to your user `.sublime-keymap` file. On my system the `ctrl+space` key bindings were not in use and they seemed appropriate to use.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+space"], "command": "add_spaces_around_selection" },
```

Hope this helps.